# PHP Cannot Redirect from Inside a Callback

Tags: php, redirect, callback

This a weird one.

I have a typical event service on my app that listens for events to be triggered that are registered with the service. If the admin edits a product for instance, and that event is registered, a callback is fired based on the settings of the registered event.

In my callback I've set up a redirect to the error log just for testing the event.

```
public function editProduct($data) {
    Response::redirect(Url::link('tool/error_log', 'token=' . Session::get('token'), 'SSL'));
}
```

The call back is executing because if I var_dump the data argument I get this:

```
array (size=1)
  'product_id' => string '42' (length=2)
```

But for some reason the redirect will not execute, no errors or exceptions thrown, nothing.

I've also tried it without the facades:

```
public function editProduct($data) {
    $this->response->redirect(
        $this->url->link('tool/error_log', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );
}
```

I've also tried returning the redirect:

```
public function editProduct($data) {
    return $this->response->redirect(
        $this->url->link('tool/error_log', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );
}
```

Both with the object or facade works everywhere else in my app so I know it's the not those classes.

I even have [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) running and it doesn't throw any errors.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Or did you code the event service by yourself? If so, the essential code parts would be useful for reproducing the case.

Comment: Are you not using some PHP functions like register_shutdown_function() or something like that? Redirect (http headers) doesn't work in such functions.  
  
Also check if HTTP headers are not allready sent.

Comment: No `register_shutdown_function()` but I will check my headers, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: If the header is already set somewhere else you'd get an error.
The redirect method should do something like `header('Location: some_url'); die();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by placing an exit after the redirect. Apparently the headers for the redirect were being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough to comment yet so I hope it's ok that I'm putting this as an answer.

Is it possible there is some kind of output occurring before your header?  I believe that would cause a white screen of death.